# Fallback function not being called when function does not exist in contract

Tags: mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have created a smart contract with a fallback function that I would like to be called when a method is called on the contract that doesn't exist. However, rather than calling the fallback function, I get the error: lotteryContract.methods.getPlayers() is not a function.

Why is the fallback function not being called?

Here is the fallback function which exists in the lotteryContract:

```
function () external payable {
    .... delegates call to another contract ...

}
```

Here is the test (getPlayers() does not exist in lotteryContract):

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); // unlocked accounts 
    created automatically for us with ganache

    // use accounts[0] to deploy lottery contract to the test network
    lotteryContract = await new 
         web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledLottery.interface))
        .deploy({data: compiledLottery.bytecode})
        .send({gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0]});
    });

describe('Upgrading a Lottery Contract', () => {

it('allows one account to enter', async () => {

        const players = await 
        lotteryContract.methods.getPlayers().call({
        from: accounts[0]
        });

 })
}
```

I thought that I could be calling the method on the lotteryContract (which has the fallback function) incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have `getPlayers()` in your ABI? You should have it in the ABI but not in the contract itself

Comment: Why would it need to be in the ABI? Surely the fallback function should be called on the basis that the contract does not recognise the function call? Is that the point of fallback functions?

Comment: Your fallback function is correct. you getting an error from web3 because you trying to call a function that is not in your ABI `lotteryContract.methods`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the fallback function get called in this case?

Comment: You can just add the `getPlayers()` method to your `compiledLottery.interface`

Comment: And since this method doesn't exist in the contract instance your fallback function will be called

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new(ish) to Solidity. How do I do this? My compile script is in a Lottery.JSON file, how would I add the method to it? thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198956/discussion-between-vitaly-migunov-and-liv-stan).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The `lotteryContract.methods` is populated with the functions that are present in the ABI so the method you are trying to call, `getPlayers()`, is not there, so the code fails with a javascript exception before even making the call to the smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger `fallback` function, the simplest way is to use `sendTransaction`.

```js
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: accounts[0],
    to: lotteryContract.options.address,
})
```